# LD: ALIGN vs SUBALIGN in linker scripts

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, memory-alignment, sections

How do they differ?

I read that SUBALIGN() somehow forces a certain alignment. Are there other differences?

When should I use ALIGN() and when should I use SUBALIGN()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SUBALIGN`](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/Linker.pdf) is
specifically for adjusting the alignment of the *input* sections *within* an output section.
To illustrate:

```
$ cat one.c
char a_one __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = 0;
char b_one __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = 0;

$ cat two.c
char a_two __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = 0;
char b_two __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = 0;

$ gcc -c one.c two.c
```

**Case 1**

```
$ cat foo_1.lds
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    .mysection ALIGN(8) : {
        *(.mysection)
    }
}

$ ld -T foo_1.lds one.o two.o -o foo1.out
$ readelf -s foo1.out

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000010008     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS one.c
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS two.c
     5: 000000000001000b     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 b_two
     6: 0000000000010008     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 a_one
     7: 0000000000010009     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 b_one
     8: 000000000001000a     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 a_two

$ readelf -t foo1.out | grep -A3 mysection
  [ 1] .mysection
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000010008  0000000000010008  0
       0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
```

Here, `ALIGN(8)` aligns `.mysection` to the next 8-byte boundary, 0x10008,
after 0x10004.

The `char` symbol `a_one`, coming from input section `one.o(.mysection)`, is at the start of `.mysection`
followed at the next byte by `b_two`, also coming from input section `one.o(.mysection)`. At the next byte,
is `a_two`, from input section `two.o(.mysection)`, then `b_two`, also from `two.o(.mysection)`. All 4
objects from all input sections `*(.mysection)` are just placed end to end from the start of output section `.mysection`.

**Case 2**

```
$ cat foo_2.lds
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    .mysection ALIGN(8) : SUBALIGN(16) {
        *(.mysection)
    }
}

$ ld -T foo_2.lds one.o two.o -o foo2.out
$ readelf -s foo2.out

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000010008     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS one.c
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS two.c
     5: 0000000000010021     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 b_two
     6: 0000000000010010     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 a_one
     7: 0000000000010011     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 b_one
     8: 0000000000010020     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 a_two

$ readelf -t foo2.out | grep -A3 mysection
  [ 1] .mysection
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000010008  0000000000010008  0
       000000000000001a 0000000000000000  0                 16
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
```

This time, the 8-byte aligned address of `.mysection` is unchanged. But the
effect of `SUBALIGN(16)` is that symbol `a_one`, coming from input
section `one.o(.mysection)` is placed at the *next 16-byte
boundary*, 0x10010, after the start of `.mysection`, and symbol `b_one`, coming from the
*same* input section is at the next byte. But symbol `a_two`, coming from input section
`two.o(.mysection)` is at the *next* 16-byte boundary, 0x10020; and `b_two`, coming
also from `two.o(.mysection)`, is 1 byte after that.

Comment: What is the significance of the left vs. right side of the `:`?